# how to serialize boost graph, can somebody give me an example?

Tags: serialization, boost-graph

I know boost serialization can do this, but I cannot find an example. Can somebody give me an example?

Additionally, I have an array which contains boost graph. Do I have to do some special works to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be nothing special about boost graphs when it comes to serialization.

Looking at the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) there are examples for arrays and stl containers.

Give it a try and post a more specific questions when you run into trouble.